# Why does this happen in php when we multiple string by number it always gives zero(0)?

Tags: php

Suppose we have a string `$str = "a"`; and number `$num = 2`;

```
$str = 'a';
$num = 2;
echo $str*$num;
```

Output:

`0`

Comment: What do you expect a string times a number to result in?

Comment: For that i think no need of posting it here ! simply you can execute and have a try.

Comment: Actually, I multiply two numbers but somehow  one number is coming as a string and it  gives 0

Comment: It isn't an integer than, cast it as such and maybe it will work... If not update the question to show what you are asking about. `a * 2` in mathematical terms makes no sense.

Comment: Just I want to know the login behind it in PHP as others language like Python  multiplies that string with that number

Comment: They probably cast the string as `1`, not `0`.

Comment: In that case, you need to use 'intval()' before multiplying them. or else to check whether a variable has a number value or a string value, you can use `is_numeric($num)` .

Comment: maybe you are looking for str_repeat, instead doing looping for that, its a default value that php serve to you, or you need to cast `A`  into integer

Comment: Thanks, @VamsiKrishna, I know it but I want to know the actual reason why it happens in php?

Comment: You need the solution for the above question ? or you want to know why php does like that ? if so please update your question. so that you can get more relevant answers.

Comment: Is the question why PHP does it this way, or why other languages do it another way? I have no idea what you would expect `a * 2` to result in anything but `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing arithmetic operations on a string operand, PHP will try to convert the string to a number.

It does this by looking for digits at the beginning of the string and will try to convert them into a value. If there are no digits, the value will be zero.

(There's an edge case for strings containing `e` or `E` (scientific notation), but that's not relevant here.)

Comment: Thanks @Robby, you answer look nice

Answer (score 1):

Good Question.
Same i did ask to my teacher when i was in collage,
The answer is.

```
String * int= infinity; //According to scientific calculator answer is infinity.
```

but we need to continue our so program it provide 0. 
it is made by code by default answer.

Comment: But In Python we get different result why?

Comment: May i know What is output?

Comment: because Python is not PHP. PHP treats things differently.

Comment: actually it is not correct syntax, so gives different answer.

Comment: @PrasannaMane, suppose a = 'a'; print(a*2); output : aa

Comment: i never try this is it true?

Comment: @GufranHasan Please provide executable code that demonstrates that. What you posted there should result in multiple warnings/notices.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said the string will be converted to an integer with a value of 0. This will include most of the cases when only alphabetic values are used. If you try to add a integer value at the beginning of the string it would in theory become a integer of that value.

I would recommend to read [Why PHP Strings Equal Zero](https://blog.josephscott.org/2012/03/12/why-php-strings-equal-zero/) or [Comparison Operators](http://Within%20the%20comparison%20you%20do%20not%20convert%20both%20operands%20to%20a%20boolean,%20but%20one%20operand%20will%20be%20converted%20to%20match%20the%20type%20of%20the%20other%20operand.)

Comment: but now in php7 you have to define variable, like $abc=10;

Comment: Could you rephrase it? If its about using an integer value into the string an example would be $abc = "7returnaseven" this would return a 7 as an integer value. @Robby Cornelissen Had a really good answer for this and I would like to refer to him on why this work as it does.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for `str_repeat`, instead doing looping for that, its a default value that php serve to you, or you need to cast `A`  into integer . When you try to do calculation for data that is not in Integer/float data type.  Usually PHP auto-typecast the variables. In some cases it wont. Then we have to type cast it manually